# Doctrine ODM (Mongo DB) Document Structure for Product with Attributes

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

How to describe a document in Doctrine ODM for product with custom attributes?
I found some details here http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/07/22/mongodb-for-ecommerce.html but it's not useful :(

```
{
  sku: "00e8da9b",
  type: "Audio Album",
  title: "A Love Supreme",
  description: "by John Coltrane",
  asin: "B0000A118M",

  shipping: {
    weight: 6,
    dimensions: {
      width: 10,
      height: 10,
      depth: 1
    },
  },

  pricing: {
    list: 1200,
    retail: 1100,
    savings: 100,
    pct_savings: 8
  },

  details: {
    title: "A Love Supreme [Original Recording Reissued]",
    artist: "John Coltrane",
    genre: [ "Jazz", "General" ],
    ...
    tracks: [
      "A Love Supreme Part I: Acknowledgement",
      "A Love Supreme Part II - Resolution",
      "A Love Supreme, Part III: Pursuance",
      "A Love Supreme, Part IV-Psalm"
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on why the blog post you found is not useful or what code issue you are stuck on? For example, what have you tried and what is the error? The post you referenced is ~4 years old so I would check the [current DoctrineODM documentation](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/embedded-mapping.html) if you have syntax errors. It seems like the general pattern of embedding custom options with the `@EmbedMany` annotation still applies, though.

Comment: That example implements only product modifications, but not product attributes. It does not have custom product attributes at all. I don't understand how to define hierarchical structure of the document, especially with variable attributes.